# How to look up corresponding value from a list?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

Google Sheets - need to convert some values into corresponding names, according to a list.

For example: worksheet has category **names**, which I need to convert into category **IDs**.
There's a lookup table that has the name-ID pairs, in another tab.

How do I write a formula that scans the lookup table for a match, then takes the value in the next cell to the right, and inputs it?

Basically, give me the corresponding ID values for ALL items on the list.

List:

- Widgets
- Widgets
- Gadgets
- Widgets
- Accessories
- Gadgets
- Gadgets
- Gadgets
- Widgets
- Widgets
- Widgets

Lookup table:

- Accessories | 29
- Widgets | 34
- Gadgets | 72

What I need as a result:

- Widgets  34
- Widgets  34
- Gadgets 72
- Widgets  34
- Accessories 29
- Gadgets 72
- Gadgets 72
- Gadgets 72
- Widgets 34
- Widgets 34
- Widgets 34

The actual list is a lot longer than 3 examples, so doing it by hand is tedious. I'm sure the answer is out there...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. After ripping out my hair for a bit more.

=VLOOKUP(P2,CF:CG,2,TRUE)

Where columns CF and CG contain the category-name:category-ID values. Category-ID is the 2nd column in the range, hence the "2". It's sorted alphabetically, hence "TRUE".

Now, copying this formula all the way down wrecked the references, since Google sheets 'helpfully' auto-increments the formula.

Using Control-Shift-V to paste the formula without auto-increment also wrecked the results, because it would be "stuck" with looking at line 2 (no matter how far down the formula was copied).

Solution: using "$" to "lock" the cell references for the lookup, but allow the source cell reference to be incremented:

=VLOOKUP(P2,**$**CF:**$**CG,2,TRUE)

Problem #2: any cells without a value generated "N/A" error. Which would insert problems later on.

Solution: adding the IFNA wrapper:

=IFNA(VLOOKUP(P2,$CF:$CG,2,TRUE),"")

(Do the VLOOKUP; if the result is NOT N/A, show the result; if the result is N/A, show nothing ("").)

Answer (score 0):

use this arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(P2:P, CF:CG, 2, 0)))
```